# How can i turn on "Stream.of" method in intellij IDEA for Java

Tags: java, intellij-idea, stream

I can't use method 'of' in 'Stream'. I tried different java version as project SDK(8, 11, 14) but still get same mistake.

**Cannot resolve method 'of' in 'Stream'**

[image of how it looks for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01iiX.jpg)

Comment: try `java.util.stream.Stream.of(...)`

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is correct. The language level does not matter here as Streams were introduced in Java 8.

So,

1. Check your imports first of all. Make sure you are using `java.util.stream.Stream`:
   [image]
2. Check also, that `public static<T> Stream<T> of` exists in your SDK (Cmd/Ctrl+Click on `Stream`). [image: go to function]
3. If it is there, try clearing caches of the IDE (**File | Invalidate caches and Restart**)